# Migrating a symfony 4 project with full composer.json

Tags: symfony, composer-php, migration, symfony4

I would like to migrate to symfony 4.2, having a new feature that is fixed.

Usually on post about migration, it is said to change the one line in the composer.json:

```
symfony/symfony: X.X
```

Meanwhile I have much more lines in mine. I'm not sure if it's because of a way of instantiating my project ? Here is mine:

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.69",
        "beelab/tag-bundle": "^1.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "gumlet/php-image-resize": "^1.9",
        "kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk": "^0.2.1",
        "lildude/phpsmug": "^4.0",
        "sendinblue/api-v3-sdk": "*@dev",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^4.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.2",
        "symfony/console": "^4.2",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.2",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.2",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lock": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.4",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
```

Do I change all the 4.0 to 4.2 ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. There was also a configuration bit that was introduced later on that fixes the version. See: https://github.com/symfony/skeleton/blob/4.2/composer.json#L56 If you have that then changing the requirement there and running a `composer update symfony/...` should work as well.

Comment: For safety reasons you might want to `symfony require symfony/form:^4.2` and so on, one by one to see if things break and make it easier to identify which component broke it. You could speed things up by using `--update-with-all-dependencies` in case any component wants to upgrade another one

Comment: Thanks, I did them 1 by one and the new feature I needed is available now. Can I remove them all and replace by `"symfony/symfony": "^4.2"` ?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I would not recommend it. The `symfony/symfony` meta package is deprecated and will probably not be updated for Symfony 5. Right now using individual dependencies is recommended.

Comment: All right, I'll keep this how it is for now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dbrumann said in comments, I updated package by package, and checked that everything update ok.